# Замена по регулярке

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения, vb.net

Допустим, имеется текст `text1(text2)text2` нужно получить `text1 (text2) text2`

Пробовал сделать через замену по регулярке: `([^\s])([\(])|([\)])([^\s])`

```
$1 $2$3 $4
```

, но получаю text1 ( text2 ) text3

Comment: Откуда тут минусатор набежал? (((

Comment: А нужно ли здесь регулярное выражение? Можно же просто замену использовать.

Comment: @kmv, можно, но мне это нужно для примера. Так как | вызвал у меня не тот результат при работе с группами, который я ожидал. Если | разбить на 2 регулярки, то все работает, как и ожидается.

Comment: Я удалил ответ, так как вопрос неясен, пожалуйста, уточните все контексты, в которых нужно добавить пробелы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясню, откуда взялись лишние пробелы в результате.

Регулярка срабатывает два раза, так как наличествует `|`.

В первый раз в параметры $1 и $2 попадут текст до открывающей скобки и сама скобка, соответственно. А параметры $3 и $4 останутся пустыми. Следовательно, выведется:

> текст до скобки, пробел, открывающая скобка, пусто, пробел (лишний!), пусто.

Во второй раз, наоборот, первые два параметра останутся пустыми, а последние два захватят закрывающую скобку и текст после неё. Аналогично, выведется:

> пусто, пробел (лишний!), пусто, закрывающая скобка, текст после скобки.

---

Предлагаю использовать перегрузку метода `Replace` с использованием `MatchEvaluator`. В таком случае регулярка получается простейшая. Но пришлось задействовать словарь с парами замен.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { ["("] = " (", [")"] = ") " };

string input = "text1(text2)text3";

string pattern = @"\( | \)";

var options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;

string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => dict[m.Value], options);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

В комментариях к другим ответам были высказаны предположения, что пробелы нужно добавлять только в том случае, если их нет. Вероятно для этого автор использовал `([^\s])`. В таком случае, для моего варианта регулярка станет следующей:

```
@"(?<!\s) \( | \) (?!\s)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте отлавливать не текст до скобок | после, а саму центральную часть:

Паттерн: `\s?\((.*)\)\s?`

Замена: " `($1)` " //обратите внимание на пробелы

[Пример](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.replace?p=XHMqXCgoLiopXClccyo%3d&t=dGV4dDEodGV4dDIpdGV4dDMNCnRleHQxICh0ZXh0MikgdGV4dDMNCnRleHQxICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICh0ZXh0MikgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgdGV4dDM%3d&r=ICgkMSkg&op=32)

Comment: Первый адекватный ответ...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, чем он адекватен, если делает не то что надо https://regex101.com/r/vB8zH7/1 ?

Comment: @Visman уговорили, поправил его еще раз :) А адекватен он тем, что дает хоть какой-то общий совет вместо вываливания сразу готового выражения с кучей скобок, часть из которых - экранированы...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можете еще 10 раз исправить, толку не будет https://regex101.com/r/vB8zH7/2

Comment: ну вы тут внутри моего ответа меняете задачу на ходу. изначально было просто - отделить пробелами текст в скобах. а меняя текст входящий можно поломать любую регулярку :) регулярное выражение работает там, где есть формат хоть какой-то.

Comment: @Visman в вопросе не сказано что делать для вложенных скобок - поэтому можно делать что угодно

Comment: @GRUNGER, в вопросе ясно сказано, что пробелы должны быть добавлена если их там нет. Ваша первоначальная регулярка этому условию не соответствует. По претензиям с исправлениями к Pavel Mayorov.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, отговорки не принимаются, так как из примера по второй ссылке скобки не обработаны.

Comment: `text(text(text()))text` в вашей регулярке тоже не все пробелы ставятся. давайте не менять первоначальный входящий текст.

Comment: @GRUNGER, вы мой постскриптум читали? Между подряд идущими одинаковыми скобками пробелов и не будет.

Comment: @Visman ваш вариант тоже не работает в таком случае  https://regex101.com/r/cV6oQ7/2

Comment: @PavelMayorov, нечестную игру ведете? Что вы туда за символы между скобками насували аж на целых 18 байт?

Comment: @Visman там символы с кодом 0x200c. Их 18 потому что 1 никак не удавалось скопировать в буфер обмена :)

Comment: @Visman ах да, чуть не забыл: *"отговорки не принимаются, так как из примера по второй ссылке невидимые символы не обработаны"*

Comment: О, кто-то уже минусует ответы! Я тут относительно активно несколько дней - а такие интриги бурлят! :)

Comment: @GRUNGER, этот вопрос получил 2 минуса, а все ответы на него - по одному. А вот плюсы почему-то пока только у этого...

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить `(?=\()|(\))` на `$1` .

Если нужно сделать по одному пробелу, независимо от того, были пробелы, или нет, то заменить `\s*(?:(\()|(\)))\s*` на `$2 $1`.

Если не надо оставлять пробелов между одинаковыми скобками, то `\s*(?:(\(+)|(\)+))\s*` на `$2 $1`.

Comment: При таком подходе пробелы будут добавлены даже при их наличии, см. [тут](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3d%5c()%7c(%5c))&i=text1+(text2)+text2&r=%241+). Именно поэтому у ТС в выражении использованы `[^\s]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Не спорю, думал и о таком варианте, но не уверен, нужно ли удалять уже имеющиеся пробелы (напр. в `text1ПРОБЕЛ_ПРОБЕЛ(text2) text2`).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю сработает ли такая замена в C#.

Регулярное выражение для поиска

```
(?<=[^\(\s])(?=\()|(?<=\))(?=[^\)\s])
```

Замена: символ пробела(!!!)

Тест тут https://regex101.com/r/cV6oQ7/1

**P.S.** Регулярка сама ни чего не выделяет, а только находит позиции между открывающейся скобкой и символом перед ней не равным пробельному символу или открывающейся скобке ИЛИ позицию между закрывающейся скобкой и символом за ней не равным закрывающейся скобке или пробельному символу.

Comment: @iluxa1810, вы хоть прокомментируйте работает ли регулярка без захвата символов?

Comment: на самом деле, конечно, не понимаю почему здесь минус